# QML ComboBox style

Tags: qt, combobox, styles, qml, qtquickcontrols2

I customized a Combobox with the following code but there are some things I don't understand and so can't fix.
First, the height of the hovered element with id rectDlgt. I ouput in the console the heights of itemDlgt and rectDlgt and they are not the same while I expect they should. itemDlgt is 40 in height and rectDlgt is 16.

The second thing is that grey rectangle that appears when I press on an element in the list. I assume it's linked to listView but it doesn't seem to change even with a delegate in the ListView.

```
ComboBox {
  id:equipmentList
  anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
  width: 318
  height:64

  model: [ qsTr("Equipment1"), qsTr("Equipment2"), qsTr("Equipment3"), qsTr("Equipment4"), qsTr("Equipment5"), qsTr("Equipment6") ]

  //the background of the combobox
  background: Rectangle {
      color: "#95A4A8"
      border.color: "white"
      radius: height/2
  }

  delegate: ItemDelegate {
      id:itemDlgt
      width: equipmentList.width
      height:40

      contentItem: Rectangle{
          id:rectDlgt
          width:parent.implicitWidth
          height:itemDlgt.height
          color:itemDlgt.hovered?"#507BF6":"white";

          Text {
              id:textItem
              text: modelData
              color: hovered?"white":"#507BF6"
              font: equipmentList.font
              elide: Text.ElideRight
              verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
              horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
          }
       }

        onPressed: console.log(itemDlgt.height+" "+rectDlgt.height)//are not the same!
   }

   //the arrow on the right in the combobox
   indicator:Image{
         width:50; height:width;
         horizontalAlignment:Image.AlignRight
         source:comboPopup.visible ? "arrowOpen.png":"arrowClose.png";
   }

   //the text in the combobox
   contentItem: Text {
         leftPadding: 20
         rightPadding: equipmentList.indicator.width + equipmentList.spacing

         text: equipmentList.displayText
         font: equipmentList.font
         color: "white"
         verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
         horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
         elide: Text.ElideRight
   }

   //the list of elements and their style when the combobox is open
   popup: Popup {
         id:comboPopup
         y: equipmentList.height - 1
         width: equipmentList.width
         height:contentItem.implicitHeigh
         padding: 1

         contentItem: ListView {
             id:listView
             implicitHeight: contentHeight
             model: equipmentList.popup.visible ? equipmentList.delegateModel : null

             ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
         }

         background: Rectangle {
            radius: 20
            border.width: 1
            border.color:"#95A4A8"
         }
     }

  }
```

So how to correct the height of rectDlgt and what is the grey rectangle above the pressed element?

[image]

Thanks.

**EDIT:** with Jiu's answer, I get:

[image]

And the new code, only for the delegate in ComboBox:

```
...
delegate: ItemDelegate {
          id:itemDlgt
          width: equipmentList.width
          height:40
          padding:0

          contentItem: Text {
              id:textItem
              text: modelData
              color: hovered?"white":"#507BF6"
              font: equipmentList.font
              elide: Text.ElideRight
              verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
              horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
              leftPadding: 20
          }

          background: Rectangle {
            radius: 20
            color:itemDlgt.hovered?"#507BF6":"white";
            anchors.left: itemDlgt.left
            anchors.leftMargin: 0
            width:itemDlgt.width-2
          }

          ...

        }
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: To get this to work, make sure to also add the following imports to the top of the qml file:   
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is the grey rectangle

It is the `background` of `ItemDelegate`, the width of it is the padding of `itemDlgt`. The `contentItem` is within `itemDlgt` padding. see [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#background-prop).

> how to correct the height of rectDlgt

Height of `itemDlgt` - Height of `rectDlgt` = Both top&bottom padding of `itemDlgt`

```
40 - 16 = 12 * 2
```

If you want both heights are the same value, you can set padding to zero. But I guess you may need to modify the default `background`.